# Why does python and my web browser show different codes for the same link?

Tags: python, html

Let's use the url https://www.google.cl/#q=stackoverflow as an example. Using Chrome Developer Tools on the first link given by the search we see this html code:

[image: inspecting google search first result]

Now, if I run this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = urlopen("https://www.google.cl/#q=stackoverflow")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url)
print(soup.prettify())
```

I wont find the same elements. In fact, I wont find any link from the results given by the google search. Same goes if I use the `requests` module. Why does this happen? Can I do something to get the same results as if I was requesting from a web browser?

Comment: It's a dynamically loaded page.

Comment: @MoonCheesez is there a way to get it's true HTML code like Chrome does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the html is generated dynamically, likely from a modern single page javascript framework like Angular or React (or even just plain JavaScript), you will need to actually drive a browser to the site using selenium or phantomjs before parsing the dom.

Here is some skeleton code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://google.com")

html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.innerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Here is the selenium documentation for more info on running selenium, configurations, etc.:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

edit:
you will likely need to add a `wait` before grabbing the html, since it may take a second or so to load certain elements of the page. See below for reference to the explicity wait documentation of python selenium:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Another source of complication is that certain parts of the page might be hidden until AFTER user interaction. In this case you will need to code your selenium script to interact with the page in certain ways before grabbing the html.