# beautifulsoup4 find_all not finding any data on Walmart grocery website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape some basic product information from the url linked [here](https://www.walmart.com/grocery/browse/Cereal-&-Breakfast-Food?aisle=1255027787111_1255027787501), but the bs4 `find_all` command isn't finding any data given the name of the class associated with the product div. Specifically, I am trying:

```
url = https://www.walmart.com/grocery/browse/Cereal-&-Breakfast-Food?aisle=1255027787111_1255027787501
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
product_list = soup.find_all('div', class_='productListTile')
print(product_list)
```

But this prints an empty list `[]`. Having inspected the webpage on Chrome, I know that 'productListTile' is the correct class name. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you tried to print `r.content`? Is it the right html?

Comment: Good idea - it prints out some html but it doesn't match what I see in Chrome when I inspect the webpage. Are you able to get the correct output using this code?

Comment: Maybe the site don't want to be scraped so it uses an anti-bot.
Try also to print `r.text` and check the result.

Comment: This is very common. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578875/why-does-python-and-my-web-browser-show-different-codes-for-the-same-link/38579174

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use Selenium most likely. Beautiful Soup requests get redirected to a "Verify Your Identity" page.

Here is a very similar question to this one, which has code with Selenium and Beautiful Soup working in concert to scrape Wal-Mart

[python web scraping using beautiful soup is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128107/python-web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Web scraping technics vary with websites. In this case, you can either use selenium that is a good option and here I am adding another method with the beautiful soup itself, this helped me a lot.

In this case, inspect the web page and then select network, please refresh the page.
[image]

Then sort with type:
In the below image I had marked with red color the API's they called to get the data from the backend. So you can directly call the backend API to fetch the player's data.
[image]

Check the "Headers" you will see the API endpoint and in preview, you can see the API response in JSON format.
[image]

Now if you want to get the images then please check the source you will see the images and u can download the images and map with the id.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Supply any UserAgent and you'll avoid the robot authentication.